# Why isnt my view data populating in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

A few days ago I started learning AngularJS (both standalone and on rails). I have the below controller, service and view setup.  Based on my console.log messages, it appears that my data loads successfully, however my view is simply blank.  I know the view is functional since I have tested it with a static array of hashes and can see that data fine.  Can someone please lend an explanation?  Also, I'm pulling data from a separate (local) app.  I appreciate all the help I can get..thanks

agenciesCtrl.js.coffee

```
@AgenciesCtrl = ($scope, Agency) ->
  $scope.agencies = Agency.all
return Agency
```

agency.js.coffee

```
angular.module('app').factory('Agency', ['$http', ($http) ->

  loadAgencies = () ->
    $http.get("http://localhost:3001/agencies")
    .success((data) ->
      console.log "Agencies successfully retrieved from server"
      console.log data
      return data
    ).error ->
      alert "error"
    return

  agencies = loadAgencies()

  Agency = 
    all: agencies
    create: ->
      console.log "CREATE"
      return
    find: ->
      console.log "FIND"
      return
    delete: ->
      console.log "DELETE"
    return

  return Agency

])
```

index.html

```
<div class="container " style="margin-top: 40px">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="agency in agencies">
      <h2><a ng-click="">agency name: {{ agency.name }}</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Console Log:

```
Agencies successfully retrieved from server
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: 
`$http.get` returns a promise, not the actual value  returned in the success callback.

So you have to give the promise the `then` callback and assign the value. 
(if you return a value within a promise, it will be provided in the next promise as parameter)

```
angular.module('app').factory('Agency', ['$http', ($http) ->  
  Agency = 
    all: -> 
     $http.get("http://localhost:3001/agencies")
       .success((data) ->
        console.log "Agencies successfully retrieved from server"
        console.log data
        return data; //this won't give the the value as an return value!! careful
       )
       .error ->
        alert "error"
    create: ->
      console.log "CREATE"
      return
    find: ->
      console.log "FIND"
      return
    delete: ->
      console.log "DELETE"
    return

  return Agency

])
```

Usage then (dunno in coffeescript):

```
Agency.all().then((agencies) ->
  $scope.agencies = agencies
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll admit, I don't completely understand the purpose of returning a promise vs. the actual data.  I will study this concept further as I know it is an important part of the Angular framework.  Thanks again

Comment: short explaination: 
The `success` callback is async, so it takes some time until it is getting called, when the http response arrives. 

But javascript is different from java, it won't w8 until the expression is complete. 

So if you just do like `agencies = Agency.all()` you dont have the data here already. Thats because you need to return a promise. It is a callback, that will be invoked, when the http response arrived.

Returning the value within the success, will pass this value to the promise function.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain a bit further.  Conceptually, it makes perfect sense.  Implementation will take some practice though!  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `loadAgencies` method is not populating the array, it just returns nothing. Maybe you should return the `data` from the server like:

```
loadAgencies = () ->
  $http.get("http://localhost:3001/agencies")
  .success((data) ->
    console.log "Agencies successfully retrieved from server"
    console.log data // this line
    return data
  ).error ->
    alert "error"
  return
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work. (actually I was returning the data, a typo in the initial post..sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have done assignment but instead of doing

`agencies = loadAgencies()`

if you do

```
 .success((data) ->
      console.log "Agencies successfully retrieved from server"
      console.log data
      agencies=data;  //Assigning agencies here
      return data;
```

it should work. The returns as i see in your code return from success callback, which does not get assigned to agencies.